# Nvidia hardware / display driver issue (TI 660) - looks like HW problems but is fixed with driver update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm baffled and need to know if I'm missing something.

My system (ASUS mobo, GTX 660 Ti, Win7 64) has been crashing every so often the past week.  Symptom is my display goes black and upon reboot, I see red lined (horizontal) square boxes all over the screen after a reboot.  I would see this during system post, and in the OS.  Going into safe then back to normal made things work for a while.  I then upgraded to the 331 WHQL driver and the symptoms persisted.  I was sure it was a flaky video card (since symptoms seen were during system POST AND in the OS) I was getting ready order to another one.

Just to see, I went to nvidia's website and grabbed the 320.49 driver and now my symptoms have gone away completely.

** What I'm not getting is why I am seeing this during post AND in the OS with a driver update 'fix'. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating may have included your BIOS revision/firmware for your motherboard in the most up-to-date driver for the 660ti. The driver that is included or initially downloaded may not always include yours.

To be safe, it may also be a good idea to update the firmware on your motherboard (I do not know the model) as it may also include updates you need to optimize functionality.

Comment: My assumption was firmware for the video card got updated somehow... which struck me as odd as I never saw anything that looked like a typical fw upgrade progress screen.  Strange...

Comment: With Nvidia there are now two components. The GeForce experience (which optimizes display settings and such for games), and your actual video card driver...both of which you will go through a full installer to update.

Answer (score 0):

Updated driver in Windows OS does not change how motherboard talks to video card during POST.